# Decrypt fields on BigQuery who were encrypted using GCloud KMS on a python script

Tags: python, encryption, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, google-cloud-kms

So I have this case where I made a python script that make some API calls, collect a bunch of data, encrypt some sensitive fields and them write it on a BigQuery table.

Everything went fine up to here.

Now I need to create a view, querying all columns from this table and apply the decrypt on the fields that were encrypted on previous step.

To encrypt the data I've used python library `google-cloud-kms` as shown below:

```
import base64
from google.cloud import kms_v1

class kms_util:
    def __init__(self, project_id:str, location:str, key_ring:str, crypto_key:str) -> None:
        self.__project_id = project_id
        self.__location = location
        self.__key_ring = key_ring
        self.__crypto = crypto_key
        self.client_kms = kms_v1.KeyManagementServiceClient()
        self.__key_name = self.client_kms.crypto_key_path(project=self.__project_id, location=self.__location, key_ring=self.__key_ring, crypto_key=self.__crypto)

    def encrypt_data(self, data):
        plaintext = str(data).encode('utf-8')
        response = self.client_kms.encrypt(request={'name': self.__key_name, 'plaintext': plaintext})
        return str(base64.b64encode(response.ciphertext),'utf8')

    def decrypt_data(self, ciphertext):
        response = self.client_kms.decrypt(request={'name': self.__key_name, 'ciphertext': base64.b64decode(ciphertext)})
        return response.plaintext.decode('utf-8')
```

Explaining it a little bit its a class that need all the params to specify the path to the key on Google Cloud KMS. From that It will give us access to kms client, the `encrypt_data` and `decrypt_data` methods who will use the key specified with the params used in the constructor.

Note that to encrypt I just need to call `kms_v1.client.encrypt` method passing the path of the key and the data to encrypt.

The big issue here is on BigQuery. I can't figure out how to decrypt the data using the same process.

My plan was to create an UDF function to decrypt the data, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `project.udf.fnc_decrypt`(ciphertext ANY TYPE)
RETURNS STRING AS (
    (
        SELECT
            # doc: AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(keyset, ciphertext, additional_data)
            AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(
                # doc: KEYS.KEYSET_CHAIN(kms_resource_name, first_level_keyset)
                KEYS.KEYSET_CHAIN(
                    'gcp-kms://projects/<project>/locations/<location>/keyRings/<key_ring>/cryptoKeys/<crypto_key>',
                    first_level_keyset),
        FROM_BASE64(ciphertext), additional_data)
    )
);
```

And then call it on the fields of the view who were encrypted:

```
SELECT
    foo,
    bar,
    `project.udf.fnc_decrypt`(col_to_decrypt)
FROM `project.dataset.table_with_api_data`
```

BUT consulting [BigQuery encryption functions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions) I just found AEAD functions, that need more than just the `key` and the `chiphertext` to do so.
It also needs `first_level_keyset` and an `associated_data`, as shown in the second snippet, things that I didn't use in my python script, using google kms library.

Any suggestion how I should proceed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things being confused here:

- The keyset that the BigQuery AEAD methods use is different than a KMS key. You can use a KMS key to wrap a keyset, but not directly doing BigQuery AEAD encryption/decryption as you presented. I mean your first script should work fine alone, but not together with the second script. You can create a new keyset, wrap it with a KMS key, use it for encryption, and store it within BigQuery. Upon decryption, you could read and unwrap the key into a keyset, and use it for decryption.
- The additional authentication data (AAD) is part of AES-GCM definition ([RFC-7714](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7714)), but it's optional (and unencrypted) (see [link](https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-kms/latest/V1.EncryptRequest)) and you have omitted it in the first script. If you provide an AAD during encryption, you have to provide the same AAD upon decryption too.